# Find closed loops between a series of connected points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been trying work out how to approach what i initially was a simple problem - turns out i'm an idiot and have no idea what i'm doing.

Firstly my data structure is like this:

```
public class Points{
    public List<Points> connectsTo = new List<Points>();
    public Vector3 position;
}
// main script 
List<Points> allWorldPoints = new List<Points>();
```

The idea is the points are connectors that create walls and from that i need to find rooms. Here is an image of what i am trying to achieve:

[image]

Rooms are not necessarily square/rectangle shape, they could L or T shaped etc.

The problem is i don't know the logic of how to approach working this out, so am looking for advice as the logic is really confusing me.

Comment: Just List of Point isn't enough, you'll need at least List of Tuple<Point,Point> for each connection and building the wall. Getting the rooms can be done with flood fill

Comment: I don't understand? The visual shows the points connect up fine using a Point which also contains a list of points it connects to.. Also why do i need <Point,Point> i don't see the relationship there? Edit: Nor does unity support tuple it seems.

Comment: I think the terminology you've used is a little confusing in your code. A `Points` has a list of `Points`. You're also then creating a list of `Points` outside of that.

Comment: Yeah its a list of points in my main script, and each point also has its own list of points that it connects to. What would be a better structure ?

Comment: Ah, so a single List of Points only apply to a single polygon?

Comment: No currently i just have a list of all points in the game world and what they connect to, i then have to find all the closed loops as shown in the image example which is what i do not understand how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Start at any point.
2. Traverse connected points till you get back the starting point. Select from all possible paths found the one with minimum number of points; you've just found a room.
3. Store the newly found room.
4. Take a new starting point that does not belong to any found room and repeat 2.
5. End when there is no points left not assigned to a room or no more closed paths are found.

By the way, your class should be named `Point` not `Points`.

**UPDATE**: I've added a working example.

OK, first let's get the necessary infrastructure. I'll implement a couple of classes: `Point`, `Room` and `ImmutableStack<T>` (the latter is used to make traversing paths easier):

```
public class ImmutableStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly T head;
    private readonly ImmutableStack<T> tail;
    public int Count { get; }
    public static readonly ImmutableStack<T> Empty = new ImmutableStack<T>();

    private ImmutableStack()
    {
        head = default(T);
        tail = null;
        Count = 0;
    }

    private ImmutableStack(T head, ImmutableStack<T> tail)
    {
        Debug.Assert(tail != null);
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
        Count = tail.Count + 1;
    }

    public ImmutableStack<T> Push(T item) => new ImmutableStack<T>(item, this);
    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this == Empty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not peek an empty stack.");

        return head;
    }

    public ImmutableStack<T> Pop()
    {
        if (this == Empty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not pop an empty stack.");

        return tail;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var current = this;

        while (current != Empty)
        {
            yield return current.Peek();
            current = current.tail;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    public override string ToString() => string.Join(" -> ", this);
}

public class Point: IEquatable<Point>
{
    private readonly List<Point> connectedPoints;
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Point> ConnectedPoints => connectedPoints.Select(p => p);

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        connectedPoints = new List<Point>();
    }

    public void ConnectWith(Point p)
    {
        Debug.Assert(p != null);
        Debug.Assert(!Equals(p));

        if (!connectedPoints.Contains(p))
        {
            connectedPoints.Add(p);
            p.connectedPoints.Add(this);
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Point p)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(p, null))
            return false;

        return X == p.X && Y == p.Y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => this.Equals(obj as Point);
    public override int GetHashCode() => X ^ Y;
    public override string ToString() => $"[{X}, {Y}]";
}

public class Room
{
    public IEnumerable<Point> Points { get; }
    public Room(IEnumerable<Point> points)
    {
        Points = points;
    }
}
```

Ok, now we just implement the steps enumerated above:

```
public static IEnumerable<Room> GetRooms(this IEnumerable<Point> points)
{
    if (points.Count() < 3) //need at least 3 points to build a room
        yield break;

    var startCandidates = points;

    while (startCandidates.Any())
    {
        var start = startCandidates.First();
        var potentialRooms = GetPaths(start, start, ImmutableStack<Point>.Empty).OrderBy(p => p.Count);

        if (potentialRooms.Any())
        {
            var roomPath = potentialRooms.First();
            yield return new Room(roomPath);
            startCandidates = startCandidates.Except(roomPath);
        }
        else
        {
            startCandidates = startCandidates.Except(new[] { start });
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<ImmutableStack<Point>> GetPaths(Point start, Point current, ImmutableStack<Point> path)
{
    if (current == start &&
        path.Count > 2) //discard backtracking
    {
        yield return path;
    }
    else if (path.Contains(current))
    {
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        var newPath = path.Push(current);

        foreach (var point in current.ConnectedPoints)
        {
            foreach (var p in GetPaths(start, point, newPath))
            {
                yield return p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And sure enough, if we test your geometry:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p1 = new Point(0, 0);
        var p2 = new Point(0, 1);
        var p3 = new Point(0, 2);
        var p4 = new Point(1, 2);
        var p5 = new Point(1, 1);
        var p6 = new Point(1, 0);
        var p7 = new Point(2, 0);
        var p8 = new Point(2, 1);
        p1.ConnectWith(p2);
        p2.ConnectWith(p3);
        p3.ConnectWith(p4);
        p4.ConnectWith(p5);
        p5.ConnectWith(p6);
        p6.ConnectWith(p1);
        p6.ConnectWith(p7);
        p7.ConnectWith(p8);
        p8.ConnectWith(p5);
        var rooms = new[] { p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8 }.GetRooms();
    }
```

We get the expected two rooms.

Note that the algorithm can be made more performant changing the `ImmtuableStack` to an `ImmutableHashSet` for instance.

Comment: Slight problem with that, if you see in room 1, there is a point which looks largely redundant on the left which kinda skews with the point count. Although that point has other purposes - so the point count might not be accurate =/

Comment: @Dave Flood fill then

Comment: I don't know what that means @Martheen

Comment: @Dave  I fail to see the problem. That point will be connected to its adjacent ones and therefore will be part of the path of Room1. Once its part of Room1 its dicardaded as a staring point for the next search.

Comment: @Dave Google it? It's just an algorithm to determine the area. So in your example you'll get 3 area, two of them are the rooms.

Comment: @Martheen yeh but then i still have the problem of knowing what of the 3 areas are rooms. I'll try InBetween's method first.

Comment: Eh, just find which of the areas aren't connected to the world border?

Comment: @InBetween i have kinda made some progress but am stuck on how to correctly iterate through connected nodes  =/

Comment: This is the correct set of steps. Go look up breadth first search algorithm. You have a special case BFS algorithm here where the source and target are the same point.

Comment: @Dave sorry for the late answer. Updated with a working example.